# How does the hash variable syntax work in typescript?

Tags: typescript

...and where is it documented?

I've seen examples like this around the place:

```
class MyThing {
  private _layers: { [id: string] : SimpleLayer } = {};
  ...
}
```

...and that works, which is great, but the syntax is confusing to me.

What is 'id'? Why is the syntax not just blah:{string:SimpleLayer}, which *doesnt work*. I've also seen {[name: string]:Type} and {[index:string]:Type}.

I've been looking over typescriptlang.org trying to find where this is actually documented, but I can't seem to find it at all.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[TypeScript: Index Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

The syntax for defining the index is:

```
{ [Identifier: KeyType]: ValueType }
```

`KeyType` can be either `string` or `number`.

You could claim that the `Identifier` isn't really needed since it doesn't get used anywhere, but I think it's required in order to force the class/interface designer to indicate what the hash map key should represent (an id, name, e-mail address, etc.). This also provides the possibility of having intellisense show the hash key name (as Visual Studio does for other languages), though I don't think Typescript intellisense currently provides this.

Comment: I've come back to this answer a ton of times, as I always forget this syntax... but I'm shocked that when I copy/paste your solution I'm confused by the slew of errors.. what I _want_ to paste is `{ [Identifier: KeyType]: ValueType }`

Comment: @brianc I can understand the confusion, but here I'm describing the syntax for defining an index _within_ a type definition. It's possible for a type to have explicitly named properties in addition to the index: `{ [id: number]: MyType, myProperty: string, myOtherProperty: boolean }`

Comment: true... i just happen to land here because the first google result for `typescript hash syntax` is this.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your question of why the syntax isn't simpler, specifically something like `blah:{string:SimpleLayer}`:

Because this would be ambiguous. This syntax already exists and has meaning:

```
var x: { string: SimpleLayer }
```

This declares a variable `x`. The type of `x` has one property, named `string`, which is of type `SimpleLayer`. If I wanted to use `x`, I would do this:

```
x.string = new SimpleLayer;
```

It's more obvious if we use a real example:

```
var circle: {radius: number}
```

This declares a variable with one property (`radius`) that is of type `number`, it *does not* declare a hash mapping `radius` types to `number` types.

Comment: Fair enough, but to be sure, the 'Identifier' in the current syntax is pointless and there due to technical limitations, rather than meaningful reasons. `{[TKey]:TValue}` or `{{TKey:TValue}}` or `Hash<TKey,TValue>` or some such could easily be equivalently unambiguous.