# How to define an interface for objects with dynamic keys?

Tags: typescript

I have an Object like this that is created by underscore's `_.groupBy()` method.

```
myObject = {
  "key" : [{Object},{Object2},{Object3}],
  "key2" : [{Object4},{Object5},{Object6}],
  ...
}
```

How would I define that as an Interface with TypeScript?
i don't want to simply define it as `myObject:Object = { ...` but rather have an own type for it.

Comment: Do the different `ObjectX` have a type or are they just `any`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the hash variable syntax work in typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070401/how-does-the-hash-variable-syntax-work-in-typescript)

Answer (score 478, accepted):

Your object looks like a dictionary of `Object` arrays

```
interface Dic {
    [key: string]: Object[]
}
```

The typescript literature often refers to this pattern as "the description of an indexable object" with a general form

```
interface Dic {
    [key: string|number]: object_type
}
```

or

```
type Dic = {
    [key: string|number]: object_type
}
```

Comment: error TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.

Comment: You cannot use a union type for index signatures.

Answer (score 114):

There's now a dedicated `Record` type in TypeScript:

```
const myObject: Record<string, object[]> = { ... }
```

Also, consider typing the keys whenever possible:

```
type MyKey = 'key1' | 'key2' | ...

const myObject: Record<MyKey, object[]> = { ... }
```

Comment: if exporting can do `export type MyType = Record<string, object[]>;`

Answer (score 15):

```
{ [x: string]: T }
```

and

```
Record<string, T>
```

usually will serve for all your objectives. However, I got to a strange point where after some type operations the first option was returning to me both [x: string] and [x: number], and I wasn't being able to use the Record, as it was a recursive type operation and Typescript was throwing an error saying my recursive type wasn't generic.

So, studying the really small Record code, I came to this solution that solved my complex problem:

```
{ [P in string]: T }
```

Edit: I also usually have this in every Typescript code I write, in a utils.ts file:

```
export type obj<T = unknown> = Record<string, T>
```

Faster and cleaner than using the Record all the time.

E.g.:

```
type MyObjectType = {
  propA: obj; // An object with unknown props
  propB: obj<number>; // An object with number props
}
```

Comment: TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.

Comment: @AlexeySh. the T in the first 3 examples is actually any type you want that your properties should have. E.g. `string`. You may use `any` or `unknown` if they may have any value. In the `export type obj<T = unknown> = Record<string, T>` example, it is a generic type. T here will have by default the unknown type, but as the last example shows, you may specifically cast it with `obj<number>`. T will be a number.

Feel free to ask for more explanations, I know TS can be somewhat confusing at first. But it is really awesome when you understand its power! :)

Comment: `export type obj<T = unknown> = Record<string, T>
` works for me, thanks

Answer (score 7):

don't know about interface, for dynamic objects we can go something like this:

```
let memoTable: { [k: number]: number } = {};
memoTable[1]=5;
memoTable[2]=7;
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a solution with Map, maybe for someone it will be useful:

```
type TKey = 'key1' | 'key2' | 'key3';
type TValue = object[];

type TMapper = Map<TKey, TValue>; // But also you can use Record instead of Map
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Object as a type use Record

```
interface myObjInterface {
  [key: string]: Record<string, any>[]
}
```