# Making a model out of a JSON map

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a model in angular based on a JSON response object that is a map. The response looks something like this:

```
{
    "response": {
        "dateOfPurchase": "2019-03-30",
        "returnPolicyGuidelines": {
            "AK": {                 // This is the problem line
                "state": "AK",
                "returnPeriod": {
                    "name": "90Days",
                    "value": "90 Days"
                },
                "exchangePeriod": {
                    "name": "120Days",
                    "value": "120 Days"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the line I labeled the problem line, that line will return all 50 states. I can't change the way the response is structured, so I'm trying to figure out how to create an Angular model that can account for that key(?) constantly changing.

I originally created a model like this:

```
export class RefundPolicies {
    dateOfPurchase: string;  // it is a string, not a date object
    returnPolicyGuidelines: ReturnPolicyGuidelines;
}
interface ReturnPolicyGuidelines {
    StateGuidelineInfo: StateGuidelineInfo;
}
interface StateGuidelineInfo {
    state: string;
    returnPeriod: ReturnPeriod;
    exchangePeriod: ExchangePeriod;
}
interface ReturnPeriod {
    name: string;
    value: string;
}
interface ExchangePeriod {
    name: string;
    value: string;
}
```

I have been told, however, that naming the problem line with the state abbreviation StateGuidelineInfo will only cause problems because that is not the name of that key.

Can anyone tell me how to make a model out of this response? Again, I can't change anything about the response. I have to use it the way it is.

Thanks!

Comment: `interface ReturnPolicyGuidelines { [key: string]: StateGuidelineInfo; }`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interface for dynamic key in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256682/interface-for-dynamic-key-in-typescript)

Comment: @ulmas It doesn't exactly answer my question because I'm unclear how to apply it. The person asking the question had two keys, "key" and "key2", and each had an array of objects. The solution was stated as having [key:string]:Object[]. Is the word 'key' in the answer a reference specifically to key vs key2, or is it a generic label for any key found in that position? Also, where it says Object[], am I specifically supposed to use the word Object to refer to its type, or do I make up a name to substitute for that?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I see where you just have key, so based on the question that ulmas sent me to I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: [key: string] is a generic reference to an object key, not to a string value of 'key' 'key2' in the linked question.