# Angular TypeScript and JavaScript treating Map differently

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have defined an interface which goes something like following

```
export interface Parameter {
   access: string;
   value: string;
}

export interface Parameters {
   parameter: Map<string, Parameter>;
}
```

I am trying to use the above interface as follows

```
@Pipe({ name: 'opStatus' })
export class OpStatusPipe {
  transform(parameters: Parameters): any {
    if (parameters.parameter["X1"].value == "true" &&
      parameters.parameter["X2"].value == "true") {
      return "Operational"
    } else {
      return "Not Operational"
    }
  }
}
```

Now the problem I am facing is that if I use any functions of the Map (set, get, entries, has) then Angular is happy and I can at least run 'ng serve' but then in the browser I keep getting error `parameter property does not have function`.
And if I change those functions to JavaScript style (e.g. `parameter["x"].access = "text"` , `parameters["x"] + "sometext"` then Angular serve fails sometimes (`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Map<string, Parameter>' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'Parameter.get'`) but browser works always.

I tried to searched everywhere but didn't get any solution. Help is much appreciated.

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.1
Node: 14.15.0
OS: win32 x64
```

Comment: What version of JavaScript are you compiling to? In other words, what's your `target` in tsconfig.json? Also, what browser are you testing in?

Comment: the value is `"target": "es2015",` i am using `Chrome Version 86.0.4240.198`

Comment: Your interface definition does not fit the example usage. For example `parameters.parameter["X1"] == "true"` doesn't make sense when `parameters.parameter["X1"]` is according to your interface an object with the properties `access` and `value`.

Comment: i have updated the example `.value` was missing

Comment: Also did you verify that `parameters` actually is a `Map` object? Your interface only defines what it should be, not what it is at runtime.

Comment: There's no reason you shouldn't be able to use `Map` in ES2015 or in Chrome. I suggest using `Map` methods and update your question with the specific error message you get. "parameter property does not have function" doesn't sound like a typical JS error.

Comment: This is the code that consumes data from the pipe ; can you add the code that feeds data *into* that pipe ? Chances are it doesn't send values typed as you expect.

Comment: i have a service (a rest endpoint which returns json) and assigned as following `this.pService.getParameterDetails(id).subscribe((data: Parameters) => {
          this.device = data
        })`

Comment: Typescript adds static typing to your javascript code. It doesn't alter the behaviour of your code at all. Interfaces and types don't "add" any properties or methods. Code that is typed behaves exactly the same as if it wouldn't be typed at all. So if you think that because you defined `parameter: Map<string, Parameter>` it suddenly has the methods that a `Map` has, that is not the case. You are responsible for passing an actual `Map` instance to your pipe.

Comment: Does that mean i have to manually copy json received data into the interface defined data structure? Does making 'interface' 'class' solve the problem?

Comment: Defining types doesn't alter behaviour at all. So you can't fix any runtime errors by changing interfaces and types. It is the other way around. Your types should match what the actual expected type is at runtime. So in your case `parameters.parameter["X1"]` doesn't seem to be a `Map` at all but just a plain object. Your static type checker just complains that you aren't using it like a `Map`. Maybe you meant to use a different type for that like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39257653/5005177

Comment: In other words: You assumed/used the wrong type. Your `parameter` property is not a `Map`, it is just an object where the keys are always strings and the values are always of the `Parameter` type. You have a misconception about what typescript is and does. All the interfaces and types you define are only relevant when writing the code. They get completely removed in the actual code. It's just for helping you IDE or a type checker to do stuff like auto completion and static type checking. It doesn't change how your code behaves.

Comment: But of course if you actually want it to be a `Map` at runtime you have to initialise an actual [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object and fill it with the data from your API response.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to have a dictionary-like type instead of a `Map`:

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [Key: string]: T;
}

export interface Parameter {
    access: string;
    value: string;
}

export interface Parameters {
   parameter: Dictionary<Parameter>;
}
```

This defines the `parameter` property of a `Parameters` object as a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are of the `Parameter` type.

Comment: This has solved my problem. After so many comments, this one actually helped me. People often don't realize that not everyone has absolute knowledge or understanding of everything. Thank you so much!

Comment: @vk-code You are very welcome. Glad that it solved your issue.