# Computed value as type property

Tags: typescript, dynamic, properties

I have a feeling this isn't possible but just wanted to check. I am exporting a constant from one file

```
export const myConst: string = 'test'
```

and importing it into another.

I then want to use this constant in the property of a type

```
import { myConst } from "./other-file.ts"
export type Test = {
  propOne: string,
  [myConst]: string      // ?
}
```

which would somehow be resolved to

```
import { myConst } from "./other-file.ts"
export type Test = {
  propOne: string,
  'test': string
}
```

Is this possible with types?

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256682/how-to-define-an-interface-for-objects-with-dynamic-keys Also, if you just want to test a small snippet of code, there is a typescript playground to help you: https://tsplay.dev/w2ErjW

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3a92w) work for you?  If you annotate `myConst` as type `string`, then that's all the compiler knows about it, so it won't let you use it as a literal key.  If you want the compiler to resolve `myConst` to the string literal `"test"`, then you should just write `export const myConst = "test"` and let the compiler infer the type of `myConst` for you, and then everything works.  If that approach meets your needs I can write up an answer; otherwise, please elaborate on the unsatisfied use cases.