# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"_foo"' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript

I've turned strict typescript checking on in my `tsconfig.json` so that I can clean up my app. I should have done this from the jump but the app otherwise runs fine with strict off. Anyway, lesson learned and the first issue I have to resolve is:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"_isRegExp"' can't be used to index type '{}'. Property '_isRegExp' does not exist on type '{}'

Here is my function. I'm not sure how to make typescript happy here. Looking for some help to understand what I'm missing.

```
/** Returns a string of parameters ready to be appended to a GET request */
    export function objectParameterize(params: object): any {
      let parameters = '';
      const isRegExp: boolean = params['_isRegExp'] !== undefined && params['_isRegExp'] === true;
      for (const key in params) {
        if (key && key !== '_isRegExp') {
          if (parameters !== '') {
            parameters = `${parameters}&`;
          }
          if (isRegExp) {
            parameters = `${parameters}${key}=${params[key]}`;
          } else {
            parameters = `${parameters}${key}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`;
          }
        }
      }
      if (parameters !== '') {
        parameters = `?${parameters}`;
      }
      return parameters;
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html) in its entirety? It covers how you would type this.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll check it out!

Comment: Now that I've actually looked at the code and what it's doing... I'm pretty sure it's just a naive copy of the built-in `URLSearchParams` API. You can replace it with this: https://tsplay.dev/Nr8PlW and it'll probably work the same way in most cases. Why do you not encode the component if it "is a regexp"? That will likely cause some issues if `params[key]` contains a forward slash (`/`).  So that's why I ignore it in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick way would be to mark it as `any`:

```
export function objectParameterize(params: any): any {
```

But if you have the exact signature for the `params`, it's better to strongly-type it:

```
export function objectParameterize(params: {[key: string]: string | boolean}): any {
```

Comment: ...Have you tried your code? https://tsplay.dev/N9j3om - It still leaves two errors, and it's still annotated to return `any`.

Comment: I've editted the second code snippet to make it work with your example. @vr.

Comment: Thanks! Your second suggestion helps, but still leaves the params[key] out with "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ _isRegExp: boolean | undefined; }'."

Comment: @ScottB I editted to code to not give an error. Can you re-check?

Comment: @MohammadTeimoriPabandi Your edit works. Thanks. Now I need to wrap my head around this to understand it. I'll try to find a YT tutorial that will go along with the handbook

Comment: @ScottB this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39257653/2594912